# How to set the default python3 to python3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I have a Python 3.6.8 in /usr/local/bin/Python3 and a Python 3.7.6 in /usr/local/bin/Python3.7 on my Macbook (In addition, there is Mac default Python2, which I don't want to change it).

By check `which python3` or `python3 --version`, I can see the current default version is Python 3.6.8. I'd like to set the default Python3 to Python 3.7.6. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "ln" command to create a symbolic link (symlink) to the existing file as:

```
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/Python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python
```

In order to be sure you can close your terminal and then open it again to check the changes default version as before.

```
python3 --version
```