# Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding - unable to solve this

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have only one Python 3.9.6 (default from mac) installed on my laptop and yet I am facing this issue. I have tried several paths for pythonpath and pythonhome including keeping it blank but all have resulted in same error. Would really need help on this.

The links that I referred to solve the issue are mentioned below -

[How to set the default python3 to python3.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811366/how-to-set-the-default-python3-to-python3-7)

https://discuss.python.org/t/fatal-python-error-init-fs-encoding-failed-to-get-the-python-codec-of-the-filesystem-encoding/3173/7

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?